# How do I resolve ERROR at line 1: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17287], [0x2781E3B1628], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, database-administration

I'm trying to open ORCLPDB in SQL Plus, which is a mounted pluggable database at the moment, to unlock hr schema/user.

```
SQL> sho pdbs;

    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         3 ORCLPDB                        MOUNTED
SQL> ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ORCLPDB open;
ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE ORCLPDB open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [17287], [0x2781DD370E0], [], [],
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ORA-00600: internal error code - means you need to contact Oracle support

Comment: You need to analyze or post here the detailed incident files for this ora-600

Comment: You can find paths to them in the alert.log

Comment: smells like this, you'll need a MOS account to read it though https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=322887473137889&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=1929389.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=ebkffgpmx_4

Comment: You could have a look here if you don't have a approved active Support (as in my case), https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2506868_1.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I’ve had a look into MOS account and not authorised to use that without a subscription I think - which sucks

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov I found the incident file btw. But its quite long, should I just jump to table of contents for ORA 600 [17287] and copy that on here?